# TableLayout in Android Studio

Tags: android, tablelayout

I am just starting to use Android Studio and I'm kinda of referring to my mentor's template for a calculator. I want to add more buttons and stuff, but when I try to change his "stretchColumns" to "0, 1, 2, 3, 4" instead of just up to 3, it adds the other column off the edge of the display. All the sizes are set to "wrap_content" so I am not sure if changing them to a specific pixel length would be a good idea. if that's even the solution.

I also don't understand why the content fits so perfectly in a 4 column setting. Is there some setting I'm missing? Is there a way he's using to set the size of the columns and rows to fit the screen so perfectly?

And I'd like to do this via the .XML file, not using java code, because I think that's not what he intended me to do.

Comment: If you could help me give the info I need to give, instead of just downvoting, because I am still very new to android studio, that would be much more appreciated... instead of just scoffing at people who are trying to learn something new.
I've spent the last 2 hours trying to figure this out, and I can't find anything. I am not lazy. I am simply confused.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a function "shrinkColumns" that I can use instead that makes it fit the screen.